# R ggplot spacing and sorting the figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data=data.frame("X"=c(22,5,8,17,7,22),
"XMIN"=c(17.6,4,6.4,13.6,5.6,17.6),
"XMAX"=c(26.4,6,9.6,20.4,8.4,26.4),
"VAR"=c('A','B','C','A','B','C'),
"L1"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
"L2"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))


ggplot(data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    ymin = XMIN,
    ymax = XMAX,
    y = X,
    x = reorder(VAR, -X),
    colour = factor(L1),
    shape = factor(L1),
    linetype = factor(L2)))
```

I wish to add space between the lines for each variable A,B,C. Also within (A,B,C) for each variable I wish to sort the line from lowest to highest by X value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXgEh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "dodged" position to make space between the point ranges within a single x-axis value, and use `reorder` to change the order of the axis (please see the FAQ link for details on this).

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    ymin = XMIN,
    ymax = XMAX,
    y = X,
    x = reorder(VAR, X),
    colour = factor(L1),
    shape = factor(L1),
    linetype = factor(L2)),
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))
```

Comment: thank you so much I will not combine them again. I tried reorder as you also included and this reorders the variables on the X-AXIS. I wish to keep the ordering on the X-AXIS and just sort within each Variable (A, B, C). Does that make sense?

Comment: I added a picture to the original question to help explain

Comment: Got it. That's actually something that I realized the other day I don't know how to do, and couldn't quickly find an answer. I'd post that as a separate question--I'll be interested to see a solution. Call it something like "How to control the order of position_dodge?"

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post another question for another 2 hours!

Comment: Well, you know how to do basic ordering now and how to make the space. I'll delete this answer and you can edit this question into the "How to control the order of position_dodge?" question.

Comment: that sounds good to me, I did find this but can't adapt it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350031/r-ggplot-ordering-bars-within-groups