# R ggplot Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```
data = data.frame("ID1" = c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
                  "ID2"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                  "D" = sample(5:25,6,r=T))
data$DL = data$D-.02*data$D
data$DU = data$D+.02*data$D
data$XVAL = c(1:6)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin=DL,ymax=DU),y=D,x=XVAL,
  colour=as.factor(data$ID1),shape=as.factor(data$ID1),linetype=as.factor(data$ID2))
```

I wish to generate what is simple: a geom_pointrange figure where colour defined by ID1 and linetype defined by ID2.

I especially am looking to create such a legend as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V1RN.png)

Comment: You end `aes()` to early. Delete the `)` after `ymax=DU)` and move it to the very end, `linetype = factor(ID2)))`, so that all your aesthetic mappings are inside `aes()`, and your legend will be created automatically.

Comment: Also, don't use `data$` inside `aes()`. You can change to `colour = factor(ID1), linetype = factor(ID2)`.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas  thank you so much it is working!! do you have any advice on the legend?

Comment: Glad it's working now. What additional advice are you looking for on the legend?

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you so much, if you click the link it will show. I wish to combine shape and color into one legend key and for line type just show linetype without the point in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map `colour` and `shape` the same way, they should be automatically combined. To get rid of the point on the linetype legend, you can [see this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16356052/903061). Putting everything together, try this:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    ymin = DL,
    ymax = DU,
    y = D,
    x = XVAL,
    colour = factor(ID1),
    shape = factor(ID1),
    linetype = factor(ID2)
  )) +
  labs(color = "", shape = "", linetype = "") +
  guides(
    linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)),
    color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = 0))
  )
```

Comment: this is an exact solution thank you. I am lastly just wondering is it possible to sort the bars from highest on D to lowest, instead of by name? It is not part of the question but sort of I'm just wondering

Comment: Yeah, see the FAQ on [ordering bars in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5208679/903061).

Comment: Oh Jeez, I forgot to ask is it possible to remove the vertical line on the points/shapes from the legend?

Comment: Edited that inn.

Comment: if you might have insight, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61383620/r-ggplot-spacing-and-sorting-the-figure